# How to update code for 1000 random sample of size 25 to 1000 resamples of one random sample of size 25

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis

The code I currently have demonstrates taking 1000 random samples of size 25 for the distribution Gamma(5,1) in R. My problem is updating this code in order to represent taking 1000 resamples (with replacement) from taking 1 one random sample of size 25 of the same distribution.

As I have said, I already have code for doing 1000 random samples of size 25 for Gamma(5,1)

```
set.seed(35)
n <- 25
alpha <- 5
beta <- 1
sample.n <- 0
xbar.n <- 0
vars.n <- 0
k=1000
for (i in 1:k){
  sample.n <- rgamma(n, alpha, scale=beta)
  xbar.n[i] <- mean(sample.n)
  vars.n[i] <- var(sample.n)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate 1000 draws from a single rgamma distribution of size 25.

```
sample(size = 1000, x = rgamma(n, alpha, beta), replace = TRUE)
```

### Update:

Based on your comment I think this is want:

```
xbar.n <- vector("numeric", k)
vars.n <- vector("numeric", k)
rgdist <- rgamma(n, alpha, scale=beta) ##This generates the gamma 
for (i in 1:k){
  sample.n <- sample(size = n, x = rgdist, replace=T)
  xbar.n[i] <- mean(sample.n)
  vars.n[i] <- var(sample.n)
}
```

Comment: So this would replace the first statement in the for loop right?

Comment: This replaces the `for` loop. You cannot calculate `mean` and `var` on a single draw... I interpreted your post to mean to want to make 1000 single draws from the same sample of gamma distributed numbers. If that is not correct please update your post

Comment: Ah yes not I understand, yeah I wasn't sure how to re-do the for loop. This was exactly what I was looking for thank you!